# uploading media to the twitter API

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I am trying to upload media to twitter via the API but I keep getting 'bad request' errors

```
HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

Here is my call

```
$image = 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JOqxgp-ZWe0/U3BtyEQlEiI/AAAAAAAAOfg/Doq6Q2MwIKA/s1600/google-logo-874x288.png';

$media_ids = $twitterService->request('https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json', 'POST', array(
    'media' => $image
));
```

I am authenticating with oauth and any other type of request seems to work such as getting a users timeline.

I am also using the libary - https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib - which appends things like the oauth token for me. Any ideas?

EDIT:

I have also attempted to make the same request with a base64 image like so:

```
$path = '../uploads/0PQ4j0yfMl1420641234.jpg';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);

$media_ids = $twitterService->request('https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json', 'POST',     array(
        'media_data' => $base64
    ));
```

and by grabbing the raw image

```
$image = file_get_contents($path);

$media_ids = $twitterService->request('https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json', 'POST', array(
        'media' => $image
    ));
```

Comment: hey @wazzaday, did you manage to make it work? I'm using same library, and I'm getting Authorization error, when trying to post image. If it's just status text, everything works fine.

Comment: unfortunately no - it seems the library doesn't support the upload method because of how the cURL request happens under the hood. I had to use a separate library which works really nicely - https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth - following the documentation gives a working example of uploading media.

Answer (score 1):

As [the docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media) say - the image should be the base64 encoded bytes of the image, not a URL to the image.

Comment: Not sure where you're reading that? I see only base64: The image passed should be the raw binary of the image or binary base64 encoded, no need to otherwise encode or escape the contents as long as the Content-Type is set appropriately (when in doubt: “application/octet-stream”).
Supported image formats are PNG, JPG and GIF. Animated GIFs are now supported.

Comment: First, use POST multipart/form-data or base64 encoded files to https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json. - https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media-multiple-photos - Note that if you’re uploading a base64-encoded, the param name for this endpoint will be media_data rather than media, which is used for raw images.

Comment: Right, no mention of uploading an image by URL. You can either link to the image in the tweet text, or encode & upload it via media/upload.json.

Comment: Attemping with a base64 image gives a different error - HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 431 Request Header Fields Too Large. Am I missing something obvious? - the image itself is quite small

Comment: What's the underlying http message being sent? Can you print it out (the headers at least). Perhaps the image isn't sent in the request body. I'd test in https://github.com/twitter/twurl out side of php.

Comment: i guess they mentioned that it should not be more than 5mb in memory

Answer (score 0):

For image urls you can do something like this

```php
$image = 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JOqxgp-ZWe0/U3BtyEQlEiI/AAAAAAAAOfg/Doq6Q2MwIKA/s1600/google-logo-874x288.png';

$file = '/tmp/file';
file_put_contents($file, file_get_contents($image));
$media = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' => $file]);
```